# Edge/IE problems with clip-path

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg, microsoft-edge, clip-path

creating a web site with a circular rotating menu, it works great on Chrome, Firefox, and Opera, but got some problem with Edge and IE. The main thing is that Edge/IE is not supporting clip-path, so do you guys know some workaround for this, every suggestion will be helpful.

I'm using this jQuery plugin: https://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/Circular-Rotating-Slider-jQuery-CSS3.html

you can try the demo here: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Circular-Rotating-Slider-jQuery-CSS3/ and see the wrong rendering in Edge.

Comment: Hi Bojan, if you're having an issue with some code, please edit your question to include a [mcve] in it. See [ask] for more info if you have questions regarding that.

Comment: Regarding **IE** (not Edge), according to caniuse.com, 1.5% of online users worldwide use IE11 and 0.03% use IE10. In early 2019, Microsoft itself warned everyone to stop using IE, describing it not as a browser but as a "compatibility solution".

Comment: **Found some Information about Edge:** Edge will get updated, will be based on Chromium, so I did download the new beta version and there is working good, so from 15 Jan 2020, new version for Edge will no longer have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge and IE 11 only supports the CSS `clip-path` property [in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/clip-path). The format is like this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1024 680" style="position:absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <clipPath id="myClip">
            <path d="M 0 108.784 A 811.972 811.972 0 0 1 811.972 108.784 L 613.832 451.972 A 415.692 415.692 0 0 0 198.14 451.972 Z" />
        </clipPath>
        <image clip-path="url('#myClip')" width="827px" height="550px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://static.pexels.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/bridge-city-night-645-827x550.jpg" />
</svg>
```

The JQuery demo is using `clip-path` on HTML elements which is [not supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) in IE 11 and Microsoft Edge.